# how to parse https raw bytes in golang

Tags: go, https

I am new to golang, want to modify shadowsocks-go code to parse https raw response bytes to check whether the google, facebook or twitter has blocked our service or not. Shadowsocks-go uses socket5 to read https data, I checked golang http module, still don't know how to parse https raw bytes. From google, examples are only about how to use go http module.

**Update**

Actually, I want to make a Reverse Proxy, every proxy node contains a shadowsocks server. So every request I want to know the destinations whether block our request or not, if blocked, need to remove the node, and add new one. This requirement need to parse the https raw bytes to check response status.

Comment: If it's a TCP proxy, it's forwarding the bytes already. Why would shadowsocks need to parse the response that it's already sending back? (you can't just "parse" https raw bytes, the client making the request is the one who can decrypt it)

Comment: While for the concrete problem maybe does not need raw HTTP parsing, the question is valid. I can imagine (and I have had) situations where there is need of a custom server, or just a parser without a server,and a library would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can make secure requests via go's `net/http` library. Just use the `https://` scheme in the URL.